# Error in my R.java file cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse-adt

I am using the Eclipse ADT bundle and recently updated my Android SDK tools and Android SDK platform tools then thereafter I tried creating a new project and I keep getting an error in my R.java file that seems trivial but I still dont understand how it keeps showing up since it is an autogenerated file.
The error is: 
*Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody*.
 Keep in mind this is when I have just created the project. Also deleting the file and letting it autogenerate still yields the same result that is the error.
Please help on how I can solve this,can't seem to find any links to a newer ADT bundle.
This error shows up in the console:
 
*ERROR: In  MenuView, unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing*

Comment: and You have done absolutely nothing but creating the project?

Comment: absolutely nothing,just when it finishes setting up the new project error shows up @Opiatefuchs

Comment: and have You tried to inster } ? But, You wouldn´t find a newer ADT because Eclipse is not supported anymore. In the future everything will be done with Android Studio.

Comment: `In the future everything will be done with Android Studio.` Not by me.

Comment: Yes i am still migrating to AS slowly but surely. @DerGolem

Comment: Even after inserting the curly brace nothing happens @Opiatefuchs

Comment: I will **not**. For a looooooooooooooong time.

Comment: :) @Der Golem.....I don´t want to do this with AS too, but I think there is no chance to stay at Eclipse..  :(

Comment: which API level You are using for thee project?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I'll stay with the good old Eclipse as much as I can. Until AS becomes **mature**.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs compiling with API 22 but targeting 21,even when I reduce the specs error still comes up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs when you update the ADT. So it is recommendable to use Android Studio.

If that doesnt work then try what @Harsh Dattani stated in the previous answer which is to Clean or Rebuild the project.

Answer (score 8):

1. Navigate to \Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\2x.x.x\content\support\v7\appcompat\res\values\attrs.xml in side your project directory.

   or

   open the AppCompat project in your workspace and navigate to   \res\values\attrs.xml
2. Find "android:preserveIconSpacing" in attrs.xml file and and comment that line.
3. Rebuild the project again.

Hope this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i did comment "android:preserveIconSpacing"  but generate more error.
i have back up appcompat_v7 and replace it with broken one and every thing goes right again .

Comment: yes , but when i target android 5 (api 22)or higher got same error again :( i thing problem is that we should update jre and adt i will try it and edit my answer

Comment: I would recommend moving to Android Studio as after a certain API I wasnt able to get ADT tools update as Google had completely shifted to Android Studio @Reflection

Answer (score 0):

i think it's SDK Manager-Tools not installed.