# How to add '}' in file R.java?

Tags: android

In ecclipse after creating a project I saw a } missing in R.java but this file can't be modified as it is autogenenerated file and as i add } in the end of R.java that is automatically removed from the file How can I add a } in R.java or any other solution

Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type Syntax e rror, insert "}" to complete ClassBody    R.java  /one/gen/com/example/one    line 3112   Java Problem
this is the error that i am getting

Comment: Welcome. You are using R and it generates wrong Java code? If so post the R code fragment involved, and explain the context. See [ask] in case you want a guideline for completing the question.

Comment: Delete your R.java. Clean your project and Try again.

Comment: check my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281296/error-in-my-r-java-file-cannot-be-resolved/29666261#29666261

Answer (score 0):

R is autogenerated, so editing it is not a good idea. You better make a clean so eclipse rebuilds your entire project, including R. If there are still errors they will be caused by errors in your xml resource files (layouts, colors, etc.)