# Brand new App throwing "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody" in R.java

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

I just created a new project in Eclipse and R.java is showing "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody" on the very last semi-colon.

I'm double checked all my XML files for errors and missteps and misspellings and empty arguments to no avail.

Here's the last few lines of code in R.java that's throwing the error.

```
            public static final int View_android_focusable = 0;
    /**
      <p>
      @attr description
       Sets the padding, in pixels, of the end edge; see {@link android.R.attr#padding}. 


      <p>Must be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended with a unit such as "<code>14.5sp</code>".
    Available units are: px (pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred font size),
in (inches), mm (millimeters).
<p>This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
 "<code>@[<i>package</i>:]<i>type</i>:<i>name</i></code>") or
theme attribute (in the form
"<code>?[<i>package</i>:][<i>type</i>:]<i>name</i></code>")
containing a value of this type.
      <p>This is a private symbol.
      @attr name com.example.reignofgodsplayer:paddingEnd
    */
    public static final int View_paddingEnd = 2;
    /**
      <p>
      @attr description
       Sets the padding, in pixels, of the start edge; see {@link android.R.attr#padding}. 


      <p>Must be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended with a unit such as "<code>14.5sp</code>".
Available units are: px (pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), sp     (scaled pixels based on preferred font size),
in (inches), mm (millimeters).
<p>This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
"<code>@[<i>package</i>:]<i>type</i>:<i>name</i></code>") or
 theme attribute (in the form
 "<code>?[<i>package</i>:][<i>type</i>:]<i>name</i></code>")
 containing a value of this type.
      <p>This is a private symbol.
      @attr name com.example.reignofgodsplayer:paddingStart
    */
    public static final int View_paddingStart = 1;
};
```

Comment: Did you "clean and build" your project?

Comment: Insert "}" in the end of your R file

Comment: I've cleaned it many times to no avail. I have also manually inserted the required curly bracket, yet upon insertion, it gets deleted instantaneously

Comment: try closing and reopening your eclipse

Comment: Done that numerous times as well

Comment: Check my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281296/error-in-my-r-java-file-cannot-be-resolved/29666261#29666261

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem like you when I change "target=android-20" to "target=android-23" in the project.properties file. if I recover it . there is no problem.
so you need to try to modify "target=android-20" project.properties file,maybe is a good way.

Answer (score -3):

Go to `gen > android.v7.appcompat` package, then copy `R.java`
and replace it with the existing `R.java` in the default package.